# Need help displaying a a two dimensional array in python

Tags: python, arrays, pygame

I need to create a grid for a game of Othello and started using pygame, but found out that **I cannot use pygame when programming it in python**.

I need help with how to convert my code so that I can display the same grid without using pygame and just use python.

Sorry if this is a confusing question as I am new to programming and had no luck searching online.

Code:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

def initialiseBoard(n):
#Set max n value
    if(n<20):    
#Define colours
        BLACK = (0, 0, 0,)
        WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
        GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
        RED      = ( 255,   0,   0)


#Create a 2 dimensional array
        grid = []
        for row in range(n):
            grid.append([])
            for column in range(n):
                grid[row].append(0)
#Set width and heigh for each square and margin between them
        width = 20
        height = 20
        margin = 5
        size = [510, 510]
        screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
#Create the starting positions
        grid[n//2-1][n//2]=1
        grid[(n//2)][(n//2)]=2
        grid[n//2][n//2-1]=1
        grid[(n//2-1)][(n//2)-1]=2
#Draw the grid
        screen.fill(RED)
        for row in range(n):
            for column in range(n):
                color = GREEN
                if grid[row][column] == 1:
                    color = WHITE
                if grid[row][column] == 2:
                    color = BLACK 
                pygame.draw.rect(screen,
                                 color,
                                 [(margin+width)*column+margin,
                                  (margin+height)*row+margin,
                                  width,
                                  height])
        pygame.display.flip()

    else:
        print("The grid must be less than 20x20, please reenter a smaller value")
```

Comment: **I cannot use pygame when programming it in python** -- Why not?  **convert my code** -- What do you wish to convert it into?

Comment: My lecturer said that I can't use it for my assignment for whatever reason, i just want to be able to do the same thing in normal python if that makes sense

Comment: Perhaps you should look into the [`turtle`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/turtle.html) module. Better yet, as it would appear that your lecturer has an idea of the form that s/he expects to see your code in, perhaps you should ask them for more direction.

Comment: Well thats all the information they will really give us, so is turtle the best way of drawing the grid?

Comment: Are you expected to draw the grid textually or you need some graphic assistance??

Comment: The grid needs to be able to visually be seen by the user and interacted with like a board game, though all i need for graphics is lines and colours

Comment: @user3591883 The Python standard library doesn't contain general graphics libraries - the use of an external library here is the sensible way to do this - I suggest you contact your teacher and check that this was what they intended.

Comment: Yes I agree to Lattyware as, if graphics are involved then there is no reason to not use a toolkit like pygame....
if really pygame is not allowed then reason should be given or a specific toolkit should be named.

Answer (score 0):

Your assignment seems very similar to the example code you will find in [python in practice (by Mark Summerfield)- section 1.3: Factory pattern method](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321905636). It explains the use of the factory pattern by building a grid for board games using standard fonts and the standard library. M. Summerfield will explain better than I can, but basically it aims at creating a grid of characters to replace the board, while using maximal abstraction with the factory pattern, and there even are fonts for [draughts](http://www.dafont.com/draughts-ultrecht.font) and such that you could use to produce a nice othello game!

Hope this is useful to you. Cheers